# Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: java, grails, tomcat7

I got the following error while deploying my WAR file in tomcat. Can someone tell me what i should do. I

**I tried increasing the heap-size but nothing worked.**

```
Jul 03, 2014 6:44:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 03, 2014 6:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 03, 2014 6:45:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [HibernateGrailsPlugin]!
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.NewInstanceCreationException: Could not create a new instance of class [HibernateGrailsPlugin]!
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Jul 03, 2014 6:59:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 03, 2014 6:59:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 03, 2014 8:03:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 03, 2014 8:03:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: Looks like you running out of memory: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` increase the `heap space` of your tomcat.

Comment: I did. i increased it to 1280 . `JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1280m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
`

Comment: Can you try exporting CATALINA_OPTS too and see if it works: export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1280m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

Comment: Can you tell me how i should make this change. Google suggest to edit `catalina.sh`, but i am unable to locate it

Comment: Just do this export before you run your tomcat. You can directly run this command on shell and then run tomcat the usual way. If you find this method working then add you own shell script which exports and then runs tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Java command line parameters

-Xms: initial heap size
-Xmx: Maximum heap size

if you are using Tomcat. Update CATALINA_OPTS environment variable

export CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms16m -Xmx256m;

The above answer i have taken it from the below link. Please refer the below link for more info

[Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in ServletContext resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112919/error-creating-bean-with-name-pluginmanager-defined-in-servletcontext-resource)

Comment: I think the link is wrong. So you suggest i should type `export CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms16m -Xmx256m;` in the command prompt?

Comment: Can you tell me how i should make this change. Google suggest to edit catalina.sh, but i am unable to locate it

Comment: Go to <Tomcat_Location>\bin folder under that you can find the catalina.sh OR catalina.bat file. Depending on the operating system where you're running your Tomcat server open the corresponding file (windows .bat file & unix / linux .sh file) in text editor & replace set CATALINA_OPTS= with set CATALINA_OPTS==-Xms16m -Xmx256m